# Use your own image for thumb in slider

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I would like to use my own image for the thumb in Slider.  A have created a copy of standard style for slider in Blend and change the thumb section:

```
<Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">                           
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
            <Image Source="Assets/Logo.png" />
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

It works, but image is embedded in the line of slider:

[image]

I want to set image size (for example 100x100), so the part of image will be above the slider line.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Hello, do you want the image to move with the Slider or static?

Comment: I want to move it.  I just want to draw a big thumb, which will be bigger that line of slider

Comment: ah trickier than I thought as changing the width/height on the Thumb in the template resizes the whole Slider making it fat lol. Will try and look into it

Comment: Did you try something simple first? like some Margin="-10" ?

Comment: Hmm... Margin works.  I have tryed to set `Widht="50" Height="50" Stretch="Uniform"` for Image and it doesn't work